# SQL Server 2008 Replace Unicode Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I just completed a project where I aggregated data from 34 un-normalized data sources into one normalized SQL Server 2008 database.

The only problem is...the larger text fields from those data sources have lost some fidelity and are now displaying Unicode control characters throughout (a lot of them).

This is the code I used to import the data from one of the tab-delimited *.txt files:

```
BULK INSERT MyTabeNameHere
        FROM 'C:\FILE\PATH\HERE\FileNameHere.txt'       
        WITH
        (
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
            FIRSTROW = 2
        )
```

Example data might be:

```
Lorem ipsum ò dolor sit amet
ááá Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsumû dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit aÆmet
```

I'd like to run that data through a SQL function and output this...

The desired output would be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: text files have 'lost fidelity'? If you are you inventing your own terms, how are we supposed to understand what you mean?

Comment: Remus a synonym of 'fidelity' is 'accuracy'.  http://tinyurl.com/bu5yxbb

Comment: It might be helpful to give examples of your input and the incorrect output.

Comment: the question is: is the file **corrupted** or are you reading it with the **wrong encoding**? Your terminology does not make it any clearer.

Comment: Check the problem files?  Are they using \n only (not \r\n)?   Bulk Insert may may be getting cute and subbing in \r\n.  Try char(10).

Comment: Those are not Unicode control characters.  'a' and 'á' are both Unicode characters.  By lost fidelity you mean the BULK INSERT is inserting those extra characters and they are not in the file?  I am not buying that.

Answer (score 0):

There are other [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) options that may help in this situation, such as:

```
DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar' -- and others
```

or

```
CODEPAGE = 'ACP' -- and others
```

When [moving my bulk operations from SQL 2000 to 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087326/in-sql-server-bulk-insert-how-do-i-use-higher-ascii-characters-for-field-and-ro), I had to drop my use of a format file and include widechar as an option to get the proper output.  I'm not familiar enough with your predicament to know if that is what will work for you, though.

> [...] 34 un-normalized data sources [...]

As the bulk documentation mentions, it's important to know the file types that you are reading in (ascii, ansi, etc.).

Comment: I'm well past the point of re-importing the data.  What I want to do is update the data already in the database.  Even if that's replacing the Unicode control characters with ''.  I'd prefer to replace them with the intended character, but replace with '' is option B.

Comment: If you won't re-import the data using the correct encoding, you're probably left with guessing replacement characters by manually eyeballing some portion of the data against the source, and then running ad-hoc `replace` queries using [`ascii`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx), [`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx), [`nchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182673.aspx) and [`unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) until you're satisfied.  @Blam may be correct in looking for newline characters.

Comment: @TimLehner I suspect the encoding was correct as those are common foreign language characters.  I deal with it all the time and there is a simple conversion in .NET but he insists on a SQL function and the BULK IMPORT some how caused this loss of fidelity.